# Why qtcreator cannot find catkin packages?[SOLVED]

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are workspaces that could be successfully catkin_make in ternimal. I sourced the workspace in terminal and then launched qtcreator. But qtcreator still cannot find many catkin packages. I do not know why terminal ould find all the packages but qtcreator cannot.

Ubuntu 16.04
QtCreator version :
Qt Creator 4.5.1 based on Qt 5.10.0

ROS Kinetic(if this is any pertinent)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294102/why-qtcreator-cannot-find-catkin-packages?%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on 2018-06-14**:
Did you setup build directory and so on when you open your project in qt?

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2018-06-14**:
I do not see options to setup build directory. If you mean going to tools->options->Build & Run->General->Directory, yes i did. Could you give me a link to what you are mentioning??

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2018-06-14**:
The error i get usually is related to catkin components. for example
CMakelist.txt: find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS):

Error:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"cv_bridge" ...

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2018-06-14**:
I figured out what was lacking. I solved it by adding /opt/ros/kinetic to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in Project -> build environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it by adding /opt/ros/kinetic to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in Project -> build environment.
Thanks to answer by amcelroy at
https://answers.ros.org/question/215834/cmake-error-while-integrating-catkin-workspace-with-qtcreator/?answer=264269#post-id-264269

---

Originally posted by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) with karma: 11 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andis](https://answers.ros.org/users/45015/andis/) on 2019-08-21**:
I had the same issue. A bit disappointing that the QtCreator ROS-Plugin does not source ROS in an automated fashion. Thank you for your hint about adding it to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH did the trick.

I found that if you do not want to do so every time your ROS package, you can include the following to your top-level CMakeList (the one you use to open the project):
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/ros/kinetic/")

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-21**:
@andis:

> A bit disappointing that the QtCreator ROS-Plugin does not source ROS in an automated fashion.

OP does not state he's using the QtC ROS plugin. It would seem he's using plain Qt Creator.

And if you *are* using the QtCreator ROS plugin: it should automatically setup include paths and everything else for you. If it doesn't, that would be an issue to solve and you should report it.