# colcon cannot build packages type:ros.catkin

Tags: catkin, colcon, ros-humble

I tried to build a packages type ros.catkin with colcon on Ubuntu22.04,ROS2 Humble.

```
$ colcon info
path: .
  type: ros.catkin
  name: rrt_exploration
  dependencies:
    build: catkin geometry_msgs message_generation nav_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs tf visualization_msgs
    run: geometry_msgs message_runtime nav_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs tf visualization_msgs
  metadata:
    maintainers: ['Hassan Umari <oh91@windowslive.com>']
    version: 1.0.0
```

but,I get the following error.

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I want colcon to be able to use catkin so I want to build this package. I tried referring to [Why qtcreator cannot find catkin packages?[SOLVED]](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/87368/why-qtcreator-cannot-find-catkin-packagessolved), but it doesn't solve the problem. There is no "catkin" folder in /opt/ros/humble.

It was working fine when I did the ROS2 humble[enter link description here](https://docs-ros-org.translate.goog/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=ja&_x_tr_hl=ja) and tutorialbot3 tutorials(https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#gazebo-simulation).
Maybe becauce These packages include packages type:ros.cmake,ros.ament_cmake, but do not include packages type:ros.catkin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catkin is the build system used in ROS 1 - ament replaces it in ROS 2. The package you are trying to build might have a different git branch, or different repo possibly, that is designed for ROS 2. It is also possible that this package just doesn't have a ROS 2 port (yet).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought catkin is included colcon, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: I believe there are cases where you can have colcon build catkin (for instance if you are doing ROS 1 to bridge to ROS 2) -  but catkin itself requires a ROS 1 installation, and is a sure sign that the package you are trying to build is targeted at ROS 1.

Comment: I see. So I will build this package on ROS1 ,or I look for package is designed for ROS2.